# Unable to merge android manifests after adding facebook sdk in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest, manifest, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to build my game built in Unity for Android. It was working fine and apk was being built! but after adding facebook SDK and trying to build project this error happens:

> AndroidSDKToolsException: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.DetectErrorsAndWarnings (System.String logMessages, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.MergeManifests (System.String target, System.String mainManifest, System.String[] libraryManifests, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.MergeManifests (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String targetManifest, System.String mainManifest)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unity version?

And dose the plugin's AndroidManifest.xml has `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion` defined and `targetSdkVersion` defined?
if the xml dose not define `targetSdkVersion` then define it. or try to delet the whole `uses-sdk`.